# additional comma at the end of python keyword arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I just dicovered that a function can be defined in the following ways:

```
def f(x=2):
    print x
```

and

```
def f(x=2,):
    print x
```

Is there a difference between the version with and without the comma? if so, what is the difference between those two definitions?

Comment: Nothing. Not only the functions, but also list elements and other stuff.

Comment: @m0nhawk, yep, sorry